# Hash test failed because input string is not in a correct format

Tags: c#, hash

I am testing some code I found on this [article](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) to hash passwords, but when trying to validate a password with the following method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a password given a hash of the correct one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password to check.</param>
    /// <param name="correctHash">A hash of the correct password.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the password is correct. False otherwise.</returns>
    public static bool ValidatePassword(string password, string correctHash)
    {
        // Extract the parameters from the hash
        char[] delimiter = { ':' };
        string[] split = correctHash.Split(delimiter);
        int iterations = Int32.Parse(split[ITERATION_INDEX]);
        byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(split[SALT_INDEX]);
        byte[] hash = Convert.FromBase64String(split[PBKDF2_INDEX]);

        byte[] testHash = PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, hash.Length);
        return SlowEquals(hash, testHash);
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Result Message:
>   Test method UT.UnitTestUsuario.TestMethodValidatePassword threw exception: 
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Result StackTrace:
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>
> at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
>      at Entities.PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(String password, String correctHash)

The test I am trying to pass is this:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodValidatePassword()
    {

        string password = PasswordHash.CreateHash("12345");

        User user = gestor.validateUser("somemail@mail.com", password);

        bool match = PasswordHash.ValidatePassword("12345", user.Password);

        Assert.IsTrue(match);

    }
```

Removing user.Password property and replacing it with the correct hash taken from the DB doesn't work either. In User the Password is of type String, and as far that I know it shouldn't have issues that the method expects a string instead.

Also the test does pass when I send "12345" and the just hashed password variable.

Can anyone see somehting I may be missing?

EDIT:

I double checked using other user with the same password, and the hash keeps changing each time, for example:

> Test 1 hashes "12345" into 1000:XV9IJ3tPys3B6PR
>
> Test 2 hashes "12345" into 1000:gqry9xl8HKavXvu
>
> User1 and 2 has a database entry for a password that corresponds to the first and second tests. A simple console print shows that data is being pulled whole and correctly.

Does that mean that is not possible to actually use the method to compare passwords?

Comment: Welllll the int32 parse is failing. Try debugging and/or writing out the value before parsing it, see if somethings being given in the wrong format. Then you may have to go back to where that password comes from to see if the problem is there. As it stands i dont think we have enough code to analyze it indepth.

Comment: @benKnoble I already tried writing the value of the password, I also checked that the stored hash is correct and that the value of user.Password is correct

Comment: Is it possible your hash method is incorrect?

Comment: @BenKnoble seems likely, each time I hash the same password it yields different results, I don't know much about the topic but Im pretty sure that makes it impossible to compare.

Comment: Well yeah one string with 5000000 different hashes could be any one of them. Im not sure how exact hash algos are supposed to be but id assume they have to yield only a single hash. Otherwise its more like a hashcode, which has collisions and stuff. Idk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `user.Password` is not returning the same value that you receive from `PasswordHash.CreateHash` in the first place. No wonder it can't be validated - it *is* invalid. You need to find out why it is not returning the right value and fix it.

Also do not worry about hashes being different every time. If you take the time to actually read and understand the article you are linking, this is the whole point.